Firewall InBound rules for UDP 500 under windows server
With the Windows server firewall, I cannot find the in-bound rule to open/block UDP 500 port ? (I want to handle IKEv2)
I can get the rules for SSTP, L2TP, PPTP, but not for IpSec !?
Thanks

It's not there by default. You need to manually create the rule.  (seen a bit here; https://superuser.com/questions/1102589/allowing-ikev2-on-windows-firewall)

Strange, because, I didn't add a simple rule, but still, I can connect to the VPN with no problem... !?

@stef The routing service seem to bind to those port per the doc, you could validate in a netstat -ano the open protocol to what it's binded; https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/networking/service-overview-and-network-port-requirements#routing-and-remote-access, so I guess a any rule on the service directly

Yes... opened by svchost "IKE and Auth IP IPsec Keying Modules". Some kind of "dynamic rule" I guess... Pretty strange behavior no ? eg. I trust my firewall list of rules. I don't see the rule 500 IKE, assuming it is closed... No in fact !! wow !

@Stef the only setting I seen is if you right click Windows Firewall, property, in ipsec you can turn off or on connection to the computer. So I guess it allow/block the port depending on that value, but there seem to be no rules for that
